# Как заменить текст, когда выполняется скрытие элемента?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Вот ссылка https://jsfiddle.net/0mrqgoxf/

```
$(function(){
    var bt = $('#bt');
    bt.click(function(){
        var text = $('#text');
        text.toggle(1000);
    });
});
```

Хотел бы заменить текст с "Скрыть элемент" на "Показать элемент", когда происходит скрытие/показ элемента. Пробовал и if-else, и метод .text(), и .toggle() - Не получается. Прошу помочь, так как я только изучаю jQuery. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(function(){
  const text = $('#text');
  const bt = $('#bt')
  let active = false;
 bt.click(function(){
   text.toggle(1000);
    active = !active;
    if(active) bt.text('Показать элемент');
    else bt.text('Скрыть элемент');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="bt">Скрыть элемент</button>
<div id="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto consequatur dignissimos sint commodi quod eum.</div>
```

Comment: Все работает, спасибо!